# Getting empty JSON entries when using Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

It was kind of hard to describe the problem I'm having in just the title, so I apologize for it being vague. I'm scraping the titles of the posts on HackerNews, but I'm having a problem when I write the results to a JSON file, in that every other entry is an empty "title" object. A sample of my output:

```
{"title": []},
{"title": ["Buffett Assails Money-Manager Fees as Berkshire Reports Profit Rise"]},
{"title": []},
{"title": ["Linus on Git and SHA-1"]},
{"title": []},
{"title": ["Machine Learning from scratch: Bare bones implementations in Python"]},
{"title": []},
{"title": ["The Future of Not Working"]},
{"title": []},
...
```

As you can see, I'm successfully retrieving the titles of the links, but every other one seems to be empty. I'm a little bit confused as to why this is happening, because the code for doing this is extremely simple (but I'm also new to Scrapy so I'm probably missing something). Here is my code:

```
    def parse(self,response):
    for title in response.css('td.title'):
        yield {
            'title' : title.css('a.storylink::text').extract(),
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You correctly diagnosed that the XPath selector is wrong. HackerNews has titles in TR entities with two TD's, the first being the rank. You want the second for each TR.

`tr.athing` will probably not greatly improve matters since it widens the selection, so you'll need more refinement afterwards.

You should either try and modify the XPath adding e.g. a `:nth-child(2)` selector, or you can modify your Python loop so that it ignores all odd TD's.

(You can also filter out the empty items after the scrape).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like I made a mistake with the CSS entries. I should have entered

```
for title in response.css('tr.athing'):
```

instead of

```
for title in response.css('td.title'):
```

It looks like HN has some other classes with the same names.